# Map 2 columns to 2 rows in 1 column?

Tags: sql

Say I have table 1 with:

```
stuff | sender_id  | recipient_id
```

and I have table 2 with:

```
id  |  name
```

I want to return:

`stuff |  sender_name  |  recipient_name`

or

`stuff |  sender_id  |  sender_name  |  recipient_id  |  recipient_name`

Right now I'm looking at something like:
`SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON id=sender_id OR id=recipient_id` but that returns dupicates of stuff as a row fufills both conditionals.

Is there a way to get the information I want in 1 query?

Comment: For which RDBMS is this? Please add a relevant tag - thanks

Comment: You will have to do two joins since you want to get two different results from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way is to use inner-selects like this:

```
SELECT stuff, sender_id
    , (SELECT name FROM table2 WHERE id = sender_id) AS sender_name
    , recipient_id
    , (SELECT name FROM table2 WHERE id = recipient_id) AS recipient_name
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with one reference to table2:

```
select t1.stuff
     , max(case when t1.sender_id = t2.id then t2.name end) as sender_name
     , max(case when t1.recipient_id = t2.id then t2.name end) as recipint_name 
from t1 
join t2 
    on t2.id in (t1.sender_id, t1.recipient_id)
group by t1.stuff;
```

It is a bit messy, but there are situations where it will be handy.

I created the tables and stuffed them with 10000 rows each (db2 express-c, 10.5 fixpak 1):

```
db2 "create table t1 (stuff int not null primary key, sender_id int not null, recipient_id int not null)"
db2 "create table t2 (id int not null primary key, name varchar(10) not null);
db2 "insert into t1 with t (n) as ( values 0 union all select n+1 from t where n+1 < 10000) select n, 2*n, 2*n+1 from t"
db2 "insert into t2 with t (n) as ( values 0 union all select n+1 from t where n+1 < 10000) select 2*n, 'C' || rtrim(cast(2*n as char(10))) from t"
db2 runstats on table t1 with distribution and sampled detailed indexes all
db2 runstats on table t2 with distribution and sampled detailed indexes all
```

and checked the plan for the different queries. I added a where clause

Two sub-selects:

```
db2 "explain plan for SELECT stuff               , (SELECT name FROM t2 WHERE id = sender_id) AS sender_name, (SELECT name FROM t2 WHERE id = recipient_id) AS recipient_name FROM t1 where t1.id between 500 and 600"
db2exfmt -d sample -g -1 -o sub.exfmt
```

Two joins:

```
db2 "explain plan for SELECT t1.stuff, tA.name as sender_name, tB.name as recipient_name from t1 join t2 as tA on t1.sender_id = tA.id join t2 as tB on t1.sender_id = tB.id where t1.stuff between 500 and 600"
db2exfmt -d sample -g -1 -o dualjoin.exfmt
```

and finally the variant with aggregates and case:

```
db2 "explain plan for SELECT t1.stuff, max(case when t1.sender_id = t2.id then t2.name end) as sender_name, max(case when t1.recipient_id = t2.id then t2.name end) as recipint_name from t1 join t2 on t2.id in (t1.sender_id, t1.recipient_id) group by t1.stuff"
db2exfmt -d sample -g -1 -o singlejoin.exfmt
```

According to this rather unscientific test, the solution by @Juan Carlos Oropeza is the cheapest:

```
Access Plan:
-----------
        Total Cost:             132.657
        Query Degree:           1

                        Rows
                       RETURN
                       (   1)
                        Cost
                         I/O
                         |
                       101.808
                       ^NLJOIN
                       (   2)
                       132.657
                         53
                 /-------+--------\
             101.808                 1
             TBSCAN               FETCH
             (   3)               (   7)
             13.6735              13.6215
                2                    2
               |                /---+----\
             101.808           1          10000
             SORT           IXSCAN   TABLE: LELLE
             (   4)         (   8)         T2
             13.6733        6.81423        Q1
                2              1
               |              |
             101.808         10000
             FETCH      INDEX: SYSIBM
             (   5)   SQL150906110744470
             13.6625          Q1
                2
           /---+----\
       101.808       10000
       IXSCAN   TABLE: LELLE
       (   6)         T1
       6.84113        Q2
          1
         |
        10000
   INDEX: SYSIBM
 SQL150906110646160
         Q2
```

Using two sub-selects as in @shA.t is a bit more expensive:

```
Access Plan:
-----------
        Total Cost:             251.679
        Query Degree:           1

                                  Rows
                                 RETURN
                                 (   1)
                                  Cost
                                   I/O
                                   |
                                 101.808
                                >^NLJOIN
                                (   2)
                                 251.679
                                 103.99
                           /-------+--------\
                       101.808                 1
                       TBSCAN               FETCH
                       (   3)               (  12)
                       132.695              13.6215
                       52.9898                 2
                         |                /---+----\
                       101.808           1          10000
                       SORT           IXSCAN   TABLE: LELLE
                       (   4)         (  13)         T2
                       132.691        6.81423        Q1
                       52.9898           1
                         |              |
                       101.808         10000
                      >^NLJOIN    INDEX: SYSIBM
                      (   5)    SQL150906110744470
                       132.67           Q1
                       52.9898
                 /-------+--------\
             101.808                 1
             TBSCAN               FETCH
             (   6)               (  10)
             13.6881              13.6215
                2                    2
               |                /---+----\
             101.808           1          10000
             SORT           IXSCAN   TABLE: LELLE
             (   7)         (  11)         T2
             13.6839        6.81423        Q2
                2              1
               |              |
             101.808         10000
             FETCH      INDEX: SYSIBM
             (   8)   SQL150906110744470
             13.6625          Q2
                2
           /---+----\
       101.808       10000
       IXSCAN   TABLE: LELLE
       (   9)         T1
       6.84113        Q3
          1
         |
        10000
   INDEX: SYSIBM
 SQL150906110646160
         Q3
```

My solutions is the most expensive one:

```
Access Plan:
-----------
        Total Cost:             758.822
        Query Degree:           1

                           Rows
                          RETURN
                          (   1)
                           Cost
                            I/O
                            |
                           10000
                          GRPBY
                          (   2)
                          758.139
                          124.996
                            |
                           20000
                          NLJOIN
                          (   3)
                          756.923
                          124.996
                 /----------+----------\
              10000                       2
             FETCH                     FETCH
             (   4)                    (   6)
             122.351                   27.0171
               49                      3.96667
           /---+----\                /---+----\
        10000        10000          2          10000
       IXSCAN   TABLE: LELLE     RIDSCN   TABLE: LELLE
       (   5)         T1         (   7)         T2
       58.1551        Q2         13.6291        Q1
         21                         2
         |                 /-------+-------\
        10000          1.0016              1.0016
   INDEX: SYSIBM       SORT                SORT
 SQL150906110646160    (   8)              (  10)
         Q2            6.81465             6.81465
                          1                   1
                         |                   |
                       1.0016              1.0016
                       IXSCAN              IXSCAN
                       (   9)              (  11)
                       6.81423             6.81423
                          1                   1
                         |                   |
                        10000               10000
                   INDEX: SYSIBM       INDEX: SYSIBM
                 SQL150906110744470  SQL150906110744470
                         Q1                  Q1
```

Answer (score 0):

And the other way is use double join.

```
SELECT 
      t1.stuff,
      tA.id   sender_id, 
      tA.name sender_name,
      tB.id   recipient_id, 
      tB.name recipient_name
FROM 
    table1 t1 
inner join table2 tA 
    on t1.sender_id = tA.id
inner join table2 tB
    on t1.sender_id = tB.id
```

Would be interesting compare both query using `explain` or `analyze`